# WP8 Some remote images not showing in secondary tile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to set a remote image for a flipTileData:

```
        var tileData = new FlipTileData();
        tileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("http://slurm.trakt.us/images/fanart/735.8-940.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        tileData.Count = count;
        tileData.BackTitle = title;
        tileData.Title = title;
        tileData.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("http://slurm.trakt.us/images/fanart/735.8-940.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        ShellTile.Create(new Uri(string.Format("/ShowPage.xaml?id={0}", id), UriKind.Relative), tileData, true);
```

However, like the example above the image doesn't show but other images work perfectly just like the one below:

"http://slurm.trakt.us/images/fanart/97.14-940.jpg"

Is there any limitation or constraint that I have to be aware of for WP8 tile images? I really can't understand why some work and others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Based on MS Doc, there are some restrictions about the size of the image as well as the time to be downloaded then you're using external Uris (resources)

> If  references a remote resource, the maximum
>   allowed size of the Tile image is 80 KB, with a maximum download time
>   of 15 seconds.
>   *from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545(VS.92).aspx.*

So, I know that the problem you're facing it with the WideBackgroundImage , and the working has a size of 130KB, and the non-working image has a size of 161KB. So, I think you should be using images with that size of 130KB or lower for the WideBackgroundImage property, and that may work in your case. I haven't found a documented constraint on this property, but it makes sense if Microsoft is also applying this restriction.

Herber